# how to print the product’s information even though each one of them has a different array

Tags: c

how to print the product’s information even though each one of them has a different array. For example, if we have 3 products with monthly sales equal to 400(id =0), 300(id =1) and 400 (id =2), this function should print the product’s information of 2 products with id = 0 and id =2.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 6

void DisplayData_F3_60897(int Sales_60897[SIZE], int Quantity_60897[SIZE], float Cost_60897[SIZE]);
int Analysis_F3_60897(int Sales_60897[SIZE], int Quantity_60897[SIZE], float Cost_60897[SIZE]);


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int Sales_60897[SIZE]={-60897};
    int Quantity_60897[SIZE]={-60897};
    float Cost_60897[SIZE]={-60897};

    for(i = 0; i<SIZE ; i++)
    {
     printf("\n___Product with ID %d___\n",i);
     printf("Enter three values (Sales, Quantity, and Cost):");
        if((scanf("%d%d%f",&Sales_60897[i],&Quantity_60897[i],&Cost_60897[i]))!=EOF)
 
    }

DisplayData_F3_60897(Sales_60897,Quantity_60897,Cost_60897);
Analysis_F3_60897(Sales_60897,Quantity_60897,Cost_60897);
   return 0;
}







//FIRST VOID nFunction
//SHOULD USE WHILE LOOP
void DisplayData_F3_60897(int Sales_60897[SIZE], int Quantity_60897[SIZE], float Cost_60897[SIZE])
{
    int i=0;
    
    printf("\n\nDisplayData_F3_60897 is created by student Raghad - section (F3)\n\n");
    
    printf("Sales Array");
    printf("\nThe array’s elements:\t");
    while(i<SIZE){
    if(Sales_60897[i] > 0)
    printf("%d  ", Sales_60897[i]);
    i++;
    }
    printf("\n\nQuantity Array");
    printf("\nThe array’s elements:\t");  
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
    if(Quantity_60897[i] > 0)
    printf("%d  ", Quantity_60897[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n\nCost Array");
    printf("\nThe array’s elements:\t");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
    if(Cost_60897[i] > 0)
    printf("%.3f  ", Cost_60897[i]);
    }
       
 }
   
   
   
   
   
 /*******************************************************************************
 -SECOND FUNCTION
The function prints the product’s information of the product(s) which has the highest sales in the month. 
For example, if we have 3 products with monthly sales equal to 400 (id =0), 300(id =1) and 400 (id =2), this function should print the product’s information of 
2 products with id = 0 and id =2. 
• The function counts and returns the number of products with cost more than N. The 
value of N= 200 
*******************************************************************************/
   int Analysis_F3_60897(int Sales_60897[SIZE], int Quantity_60897[SIZE], float Cost_60897[SIZE])
   {
    int largest,i,N=200,count=0;
    char INFO[60897]= "Raghad_Sami_Section_F3_ID 60897";
    printf("\n\nFunction Analysis_F3_60897 is created by student %s\n\n",INFO);
    
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
       largest = Sales_60897[0];
   if (Sales_60897[i] > largest)
   {
     largest = Sales_60897[i];
   }
   if(Cost_60897[i]>N)
   {
       count++;
   }
   
   }
    
    printf("\t-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\tHIGHEST SALES LIST\n");
    printf("\t-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\tProduct NO#\t Monthly Sales\t Quantity\t Cost\n");
    printf("\t\tProduct %d:\t %d\t\t %d\t %.3f\t\n",i,largest,Quantity_60897[i],Cost_60897[i]);
    printf("\t\tProduct %d:\t %d\t\t %d\t %.3f\t\n",i,largest,Quantity_60897[i],Cost_60897[i]);
    printf("\t-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n\tThe count of products with cost more than 200= %d",count);
    printf("\n\t-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
  
  return count;
   }
```

Also I struggled doing this part and the EOF is not working:
Prompt the user to enter all products’ information (Sales, Quantity and Cost) until user
enters EOF. When the user enters EOF, the main function should stop reading and assign
-1 * yourStudentID, to the remaining elements of all arrays. Note that the user should enter
3 values for each product. If the user enters successfully one or two values terminated by
EOF for a product, the program should assign the value = -1 * yourStudentID to all elements
of this product and stop reading from the standard input.

The expected output should look like this:-
[excepted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAMWu.png)

Comment: In the initializations of the arrays, what is `-1*60897` supposed to do? If you want to initialize the *first* (and only the first) element to `-60897` why not write that directly?

Comment: Also remember that the specified array size is the number of elements in the array, not the top index. That means an array of `SIZE` elements will have indexes from `0` to `SIZE - 1`. Your loop `for(i = 0; i<=SIZE ; i++)` will include `SIZE` as an (out of bounds) index.

Answer (score 0):

> EOF is not working

You compared with EOF, but programmed nothing depending on the outcome. In order to do this as well as *assign* *-1 * yourStudentID* *to* *elements*, change

```
        if((scanf("%d%d%f",&Sales_60897[i],&Quantity_60897[i],&Cost_60897[i]))!=EOF)
 
    }
```

to

```
        if (scanf("%d%d%f", &Sales_60897[i], &Quantity_60897[i], &Cost_60897[i]) < 3)
            break;  // stop reading
    }
    // assign -1 * yourStudentID to all the remaining elements of all product arrays:
    while (i<SIZE) Sales_60897[i] = Quantity_60897[i] = Cost_60897[i] = -60897, ++i;
```

> if we have 3 products with monthly sales equal to 400(id =0), 300(id =1) and 400 (id =2), this function should print the product’s information of 2 products with id = 0 and id =2.

You erroneously put the initialization of `largest` into the loop instead of before it. In order to correct this as well as avoid handling non-existing products, change

```
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
       largest = Sales_60897[0];
```

to

```
    largest = Sales_60897[0];
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE && Cost_60897[i] > 0; i++)
    {
```

In order to achieve that `The function prints the product’s information of the product(s) which has the highest sales in the month`, you have to loop again; change

```
    printf("\t\tProduct %d:\t %d\t\t %d\t %.3f\t\n",i,largest,Quantity_60897[i],Cost_60897[i]);
    printf("\t\tProduct %d:\t %d\t\t %d\t %.3f\t\n",i,largest,Quantity_60897[i],Cost_60897[i]);
```

to

```
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE && Cost_60897[i] > 0; i++) if (Sales_60897[i] == largest)
        printf("\t\tProduct %d:\t %d\t\t %d\t\t %.2f\n", i, largest, Quantity_60897[i], Cost_60897[i]);
```